# Is there any way to transform a string with object-to-object syntax?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, parsing

A given function gives me the following feedback:

```js
[
    "users[0].name is invalid",
    "date is invalid",
    "address.ZIP is invalid"
]
```

How can I take this output with object syntax and transform it into something like:

```js
{
     users: [{name: 'is invalid'}],
     date: 'is invalid',
     address: {
        ZIP: 'is invalid'
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it was created the other way round. Regex is a double edged sword, but probably, you'd need that.

Comment: _"output with object syntax"_? That's an array with two error messages, with one of them being strangely formatted o.O

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string into address part and value and get the right structure and assign the value.

```js
const
    setValue = (object, address, value) => {
        const
            hasBrackets = s => /^\[.+\]$/.test(s),
            path = address.split(/\.|(?=\[)/),
            types = path.map((_, i, a) => hasBrackets(a[i + 1]) ? [] : {}),
            keys = path.map(s => hasBrackets(s) ? s.slice(1, -1) : s),
            last = keys.pop();

        keys.reduce((r, k, i) => r[k] ??= types[i], object)[last] = value;
    },
    data = ["users[0].name is invalid", "date is invalid", "address.ZIP is invalid"],
    result = data.reduce((r, s) => {
        const [k, v] = s.match(/[^\s]+|.+$/g);
        setValue(r, k, v.slice(1)) ;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively reduce the keys by first determining the keys, and then iterating over the pairs of key/values and reducing them onto a result object.

```js
const main = () => {
  const data = [
    "users[0].name is invalid",
    "users[0].address is invalid",
    "users[1].title is invalid",
    "date is invalid",
    "address.ZIP is invalid"
  ];

  console.log(apply(data));
};

const apply = (data) =>
  data.reduce((result, val, index) => {
    const
      pos = val.indexOf(' '),
      key = val.substring(0, pos),
      value = val.substring(pos + 1);
    applyPair(result, key, value);
    return result;
  }, {});

const applyPair = (ref, key, value) => {
  const [headKey, ...tailKeys] = key.split(/\./);
  if (headKey.endsWith(']')) {
    const [ arrKey, arrIndex ] = parseArrayKey(headKey);
    ref[arrKey] = ref[arrKey] || [];
    const obj = ref[arrKey][arrIndex] || {};
    applyPair(obj, tailKeys.join('.'), value);
    ref[arrKey][arrIndex] = obj;
  } else {
    if (tailKeys.length > 0) {
      const objKey = headKey;
      ref[objKey] = {};
      applyPair(ref[objKey], tailKeys.join('.'), value);
    } else {
      ref[key] = value;
    }
  }
};

const parseArrayKey = (key) =>
  (([m, k, i]) => [k, parseInt(i, 10)])(key.match(/^(\w+)\[(\d+)\]$/));

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Result

```json
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "is invalid",
      "address": "is invalid"
    },
    {
      "title": "is invalid"
    }
  ],
  "date": "is invalid",
  "address": {
    "ZIP": "is invalid"
  }
}
```